# Configuring Kafka Connect HDFSinkNode for Kerberos authentication

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kerberos, apache-kafka-connect

At https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html the following example properties are listed:

```
hdfs.authentication.kerberos=true
connect.hdfs.principal=connect-hdfs/_HOST@YOUR-REALM.COM
connect.hdfs.keytab=path to the connector keytab
hdfs.namenode.principal=namenode principal
```

Sadly the docs for the config options at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/configuration_options.html are brief to the point of being nearly useless.

As a consumer of Hadoop and not an admin, I have a very hazy understanding of how it is configured.

Could somebody please explain what the `connect.hdfs.principal` and `hdfs.namenode.principal` are for?

Answer (score 0):

A principal is like a username in Kerberos. If you're a consumer of Hadoop, and you need to kinit your keytab before working with any data, you've been assigned a principal. The Connect service should have its own keytab and thus principal, that's the first property listed

You'd have to find who setup Kerberos for the Hadoop cluster (i.e. the admin) to find out what the Namenode principal is, but short answer is that those settings are for authentication to make write requests to HDFS. Although I'm not sure why you explicitly need the Namenode principal, Connect (as a Hadoop client) contacts the namenode to write data, so there might be some validation that happens there internally